# How do I return a byte array from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, marshalling

So I've been struggling with this for a little bit. I'm trying to make my own AES 128 library to use with one of my programs. The library tests out and works in C++ (well for the encrypt function.. I haven't implemented the others) The 'Encrypt' function is like this:

**NEW CODE**

```
void Aes128Class::EncryptBlock(BYTE* outBlock, const BYTE* inBlock, const BYTE* cipherBlock)
{
    BYTE temp[16] = {0x00};
    Galois::XorBlock(temp, inBlock);
    Galois::XorBlock(temp, cipherBlock);

    BYTE expandedKey[176] = {0x00};
    memcpy(expandedKey, Key, 16);
    Galois::expand_key(expandedKey);

    Galois::XorBlock(temp, expandedKey);
    for(int i=16; i<160; i+=16)
    {
        Galois::DoRound(temp, &expandedKey[i]);
    }
    Galois::SubBytes(temp);
    Galois::ShiftRows(temp);
    Galois::XorBlock(temp, &expandedKey[160]);

    memcpy(outBlock, temp, 16);
}
void Aes128Class::EncryptData(BYTE* outBlock, size_t& outlen, const BYTE* inBlock, size_t length)
{
    float blockSize = (float)(length/16);
    blockSize = ceilf(blockSize);
    int newLength = (int)(blockSize*16);
    BYTE* temp = (BYTE*)malloc(newLength);
    BYTE* padd = (BYTE*)malloc(newLength);
    memset(temp, 0, newLength);
    memcpy(padd, inBlock, length);
    EncryptBlock(temp, padd, IV);
    for (int i=1; i<blockSize; i++)
    {
        EncryptBlock(&temp[i*16], &padd[i*16], &temp[(i-1)*16]);
    }
    outlen = newLength;
    memcpy(outBlock, temp, newLength);
}
```

The idea is that if the `plainText` is not in a 16-byte block increment then I force it to be. So this makes for a variable size byte array.  It works in my `C++` tests, but when I call it in `C#` I get a few different errors... This will take a minute to describe.

```
    [DllImport("CppAes128.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
        EntryPoint = "?EncryptData@Aes128Class@@QAEXPAEAAIPBEI@Z")]
    static extern void EncryptData(IntPtr pClass, ref IntPtr outblock, [Out]int OutLength, byte[] inBlock, int length);
```

When I call this I get valid pointers to both the `array`, and the outlength. The way it looks right now causes an access violation, but I can get that structure to work if I change `[Out]int OutLength` to `ref IntPtr`.  Interestingly, if I do `ref int` or `ref uint` it still "works". So if I do that I try to read the `intptr` and then I get an access violation. I am compiling this as a `x86 project` in `.NET 4.0` (since I read somewhere that 3.5 had some bugs with access...)

Here is what I've tried in `C#`. It's a little garbled as I've been playing with it for hours (sorry):

```
    public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] plainText, int length)
    {
        byte[] enc = null;
        int len = 0;
        IntPtr pArray = IntPtr.Zero;
        EncryptData(theClass, ref pArray, len, plainText, length);

        Console.WriteLine(len);
        //enc = new byte[len];
        //Marshal.Copy(pArray, enc, 0, len);
        //Marshal.Release(pArray);
        //try
        //{
        //    int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
        //    //IntPtr unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10 * elementSize);
        //    Console.WriteLine("Reading unmanaged memory:");
        //    // Print the 10 elements of the C-style unmanagedArray 
        //    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("{0:X2}:", Marshal.ReadByte(pArray, i));
        //    }

        //    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pArray);

        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}", ex.Source, ex.Message);
        //    Console.WriteLine("Win32({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        //}
        //Marshal.Release(pArray);
        return enc;
    }
```

The only time this worked is when I just made a static-size array and didn't use `ref` or `marshal` copy or anything.. I think my signature was something like this

```
static extern void EncryptData(IntPtr pClass, byte[] outBlock, byte[] inBlock, int length);
```

That almost worked, but the problem was that when I did a `foreach` loop on that `array` it was always the size that i put.. frustrating to say the least.

So what am I doing wrong? how can I get this to work? I am so frustrated with it. Thank you

Oh and FYI, this is so I cannot be dependent on the `cryptlib` anymore. I'm trying to recompile a different project, which uses `cryptlib`, as a static library and not shared, which causes some problems with my compiled options and is too big of a hassle to change back.

**EDITED to show more code**

This is the tests that I use. I found a webpage that showed a bunch of tests, so this is me implementing this.

```
void VerifyEncrypt16(const BYTE* expected, const BYTE* key, const BYTE* iv, const BYTE* plainText)
{
    BYTE actual[16] = {0x00};
    Aes128Class aes;
    aes.SetKey(key, 16);
    aes.SetIV(iv, 16);
    size_t len = 0;
    aes.EncryptData(actual, len, plainText, 16);
    _ASSERT(CompareTwoArrays(expected, actual));
}
void VerifyEncrypt16String(const char* expected, const char* key, const char* iv, const char* plainText)
{
    BYTE e[16];
    BYTE k[16];
    BYTE i[16];
    BYTE p[16];

    ByteUtil::StringToHex(expected, e);
    ByteUtil::StringToHex(key, k);
    ByteUtil::StringToHex(iv, i);
    ByteUtil::StringToHex(plainText, p);

    VerifyEncrypt16(e, k, i, p);
}
void CheckEncrypt16(void)
{
    _RPT0(_CRT_WARN, "Checking Encryption of a 16 byte number IV set to 0\n");
    //AESVS GFSbox test data for CBC
    VerifyEncrypt16String("0336763e966d92595a567cc9ce537f5e","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","f34481ec3cc627bacd5dc3fb08f273e6");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("a9a1631bf4996954ebc093957b234589","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","9798c4640bad75c7c3227db910174e72");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("ff4f8391a6a40ca5b25d23bedd44a597","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","96ab5c2ff612d9dfaae8c31f30c42168");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("dc43be40be0e53712f7e2bf5ca707209","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","6a118a874519e64e9963798a503f1d35");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("92beedab1895a94faa69b632e5cc47ce","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","cb9fceec81286ca3e989bd979b0cb284");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("459264f4798f6a78bacb89c15ed3d601","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","b26aeb1874e47ca8358ff22378f09144");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("08a4e2efec8a8e3312ca7460b9040bbf","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","58c8e00b2631686d54eab84b91f0aca1");

    //AESVS KeySbox test data for CBC
    VerifyEncrypt16String("6d251e6944b051e04eaa6fb4dbf78465","10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000");
    //A TON OF MORE TESTS! etc etc etc        VerifyEncrypt16String("5c005e72c1418c44f569f2ea33ba54f3","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe");
    VerifyEncrypt16String("3f5b8cc9ea855a0afa7347d23e8d664e","00000000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000000","ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
}
```

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13123962/175157). In a nutshell, C# can't know how much memory you allocated in the C++ code.

Comment: I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is but I would just like to point out that C# includes some great cryptography classes in the [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) that work great.

Comment: A necessary starting point for interop with C++ code is that you *start* with C++ code that can be safely called from other C++ code.  You are not there yet, you are leaking memory badly and a C++ caller would not have any guess at the required buffer size either.  These problems to not get better when you make the call from C#.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I've used that namespace and love it. I think i was just being a sissy about needing to use C# to test with, but I would like to have the ability to use this driver in C# if I want to as this particular for another program.

Comment: @Alex I have not tried the method that is suggested in that post, I will give it a shot. I just found a file (I think from wiki) that has about 300 tests for this, and they all passed in C++.. I disabled the call in C# to this driver except to call the RunAllTests method.

Comment: @HansPassant I love it when you comment on my code because you help me understand C++ so much better. It gets me started with a bunch of research. I am afraid that I don't understand how I am leaking memory. I am going to edit my post and add a bit more of my code to see if that is still the case. If i am can you please let me know where and why. I've never been good with C++ and memory leaks... the sad thing is that I *thought* I was getting the hang of it. :(

Comment: @RobertSnyder Fair enough, I just wanted to make sure you aware that C# already had Cryptography classes, including AES, before you did too much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still looking for answer, this example gives a starting point.

Basically, start from allocate memory block in native function call, than invoke call - back to managed where you pass ( by ref ) array and its size saved from the original list of input parameters.

This way you allocate memory block for managed code in managed code and edit it with content from native.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ektebyzx.aspx

An alternate method would be nice to find, performance compare would be a bonus :)

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I've found the easiest way to do this is to wrap the unmanaged C++ call with a managed C++ call. In the managed C++, you can copy the data in a straight forward C++ manner (by pinning the data structure) and passing it back to C#